# Как конвертировать римские цифры в арабские?

Tags: алгоритм, swift

Пример кода:

```
func romanToDecimal(romeChar: String) {
    var result = 0
    var maxValue = 0
    let romeCh = romeChar.uppercased().replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
    let romeNumerals = ["M": 1000, "D": 500, "C": 100, "L": 50, "X": 10, "V": 5, "I": 1]

    for vp in romeNumerals {
        let val = vp.value
        let key = vp.key
        if (romeCh.range(of: key) != nil) {

            maxValue = max(val, maxValue)
            result += val == maxValue ? val : -val
        }
    }
    print(result)
}
```

> Проблема в том, что происходит неправильное исчисление конечного результата

Comment: первый раз вижу swift но что то мне подсказывает, что как только в строке найдено M (а оно по идее ищется первым, ведь оно в начале массива) то maxValue станет равно 1000 и при всех последующих проверках таковым и останется (ведь оно больше остальных чисел). И `romeCh.range(of: key)` проверяет наверное наличие какой-то цифры, но не учитывает количество цифр и VIII скорее всего будет посчитано как 5+1

Comment: и вообще вот та проверка с maxValue наверняка рассчитана на обработку входной строки по порядку (что бы понять какая цифра раньше) но цикл почему то по массиву цифр а не по строке ...

Comment: судя по всему логика не правильная - попробовал MCM, получил 1100 вместо 1900.

Comment: Да нет оно берет как то значение каторое нужно. Например XC вичесляет верно 90 а вот если 3 и больше символов то неверно

Comment: внимательно прочитайте первые мои 2 комментария. оно в принципе не способно более 2х букв и то стоящих в нужном порядке перевести. попробуйте, `I` по этому алгоритмо должно дать 1, А вот `III` по тому что я тут вижу так же будет равно 1 потому как я не вижу где бы здесь считалось количество цифр

Comment: @Mike ага, проверил - III = 1

Comment: Не подскажете как ето исправить?

Comment: @OrestMykha так вам что надо то? просто решение проблемы? Ну вот например (на objC, не думаю что перевести в свифт большая проблема) https://bitbucket.org/exister/roman-numbers-converter/src/ed0559cc63ee/roman_converter/RomanNumber.m?fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: алгоритм должен идти по очереди по входной строке, т.е. по romeCh (я не знаю как в swift перебирать символы строки). В идеале надо иметь возможность заглянуть на 1 символ вперед. Берем текущий символ, получаем его значение в массиве если следующий за ним символ строки больше, то берем данный со знаком минус. собственно все

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм предложенный @Qwertiy переписанный на свифт в вольной форме

```
func convert(roman:String) -> Int {
    let romeNumerals = ["M": 1000, "D": 500, "C": 100, "L": 50, "X": 10, "V": 5, "I": 1]
    var result = 0

    for (index, i) in roman.characters.enumerated() {
            if(index < roman.characters.count-1 && romeNumerals[String(i)]! < romeNumerals[String(roman.characters[roman.index(roman.startIndex, offsetBy: index+1)])]!) {
                result -= romeNumerals[String(i)]!
            } else {
                result += romeNumerals[String(i)]!
            }
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Очень благодарен!

Answer (score 3):

Вот правильный алгоритм, как его переписать на свифт, я не знаю:

```js
function convert(roman) {
  var values = {I: 1, V: 5, X: 10, L: 50, C: 100, D: 500, M: 1000};
  var digits = Object.keys(values);

  roman = roman.toUpperCase();
  var res = 0;

  for (var q=0; q<roman.length; ++q) {
    if (digits.indexOf(roman[q]) < digits.indexOf(roman[q+1])) {
      res -= values[roman[q]];
    } else {
      res += values[roman[q]];
    }
  }

  return res;
}

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  document.querySelector('output').textContent = convert(e.target.value);
});
```

```css
input:invalid + output { display: none }
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="[IVXLCDMivxlcdm]+">
<output></output>
```

Comment: интересно, насколько правильно преобразовывать строки типа "xxiiiiiiiiiiivi". ЕМНИП, есть две системы записи чисел римскими цифрами, и упомянутая мной строка не в одно из них не вписывается. По идее в таком случае, надо бросать исключение, или что там в %языке_вопроса% принято... з.ы. я не придираюсь)) просто задумался, как правильней делать, если бы сам делал

Comment: @4per, ага, но проверку корректности никто не просил. Если число записано корректно (в том числе, в упрощённой форме), то всё работает. Если некорректно.. Что ж, тоже не падает :)

Comment: традиционно, считается что, только один символ может быть слева от большего. т.е. 8 можно записать так VIII но нельзя так IIX

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, упрощённой формой считается `IL` вместо `XLIX` и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

На python - вдруг кому пригодится:

```
def romanToInt(self, s: str) -> int:
        res=0
        rtoa={
            'I':1,
            'V':5,
            'X':10,
            'L':50,
            'C':100,
            'D':500,
            'M':1000
        }

        for i in range(len(s)-1): 
            if (rtoa[s[i]]<rtoa[s[i+1]]):
                res=res-rtoa[s[i]]
            elif (rtoa[s[i]]>=rtoa[s[i+1]]):
                res=res+rtoa[s[i]]

        res=res+rtoa[s[len(s)-1]]

        return res
```